# API / App having issues

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm getting connection issues in the app. Half the time I try to view a question or post something, it either times out, or gives me a "make sure you're connected to the internet" error.

It's highly unlikely this is a problem on my end. I have a full wifi connection, and everything else loads fine. I'm also having the same issues on LTE.

Comment: I repro'd just now, but after retrying, it seems okay? Could you retry it now? Probably API server hiccup.

Comment: Ya, seems fine now. Ofc it would go down for exactly the duration of my break.

Comment: Apparently, the API is still hiccuping for me...

Comment: Working fine here: Android 7.0 on Moto G5 Plus.

Comment: I still getting intermittent loading issues, again, with full wifi. I'm assuming this is still related.

Comment: I just tried to load my profile from the left-hand menu, and got "cannot loaf profile content. Make sure you're connected to the internet". I definitely am.

Comment: Probably a bit late, but [Tim](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6820917#6820917) said that "*We've been having some redis-y issues all day, all kinds of stuff might have got a bit wonky*"

Comment: @HTTPS Oh, cool. Thanks.